# error while trying to install opencv by make command

Tags: python, image, opencv, ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to install opencv on my ubuntu but after `make -j6` command I see this error :

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target ittnotify
[ 28%] Built target ittnotify
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target IlmImf
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target libprotobuf
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_core
[ 28%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o
[ 28%] Built target IlmImf
[ 28%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
[ 28%] Built target opencv_core
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_flann
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_flann.so
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_ml
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_ml.so
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_imgproc
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
[ 28%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 28%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 28%] Built target opencv_imgproc
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_objdetect
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_video
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_video.so
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_photo
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_photo.so
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_dnn
[ 28%] Building CXX object modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/grfmt_webp.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/rgbe.cpp.o
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so
/home/user/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_webp.cpp:47:10: fatal error: webp/decode.h: No such file or directory
 #include <webp/decode.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/build.make:285: recipe for target 'modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/grfmt_webp.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/grfmt_webp.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 28%] Built target opencv_video
[ 28%] Built target opencv_objdetect
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target opencv_shape
[ 28%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_shape.so
[ 28%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 28%] Built target opencv_shape
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2256: recipe for target 'modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 28%] Built target opencv_dnn
Makefile:165: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't have any idea why this happen?

**Update:** I use these commands for installing:

$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_cont...

Comment: How did you get the opencv source? Download an archive? Clone from Github? Which branch?

Comment: You have not shown the actual error.  Look back at the output of the build and find the error messages, then post those.  There's nothing we can say from this information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.